# Are there any other "hidden" bits of dialogue like this in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

OK, so the above video is a guy playing through *This is the part where he kills us...*  Initially, the guy does the proper thing, and portals through the opening provided by the lunar paint to make his escape from the platform.  I thought that'd be that, but he returns when Wheatley implores to player to go back to the platform, and then Wheatley gives some hilarious dialogue about "resetting the death trap", asking us to "jump into the pit", and acting surprised when the girl actually does do so.

My question is: Are there any other such funny/humorous/interesting bits of dialogue, any events really, that one can find in Portal 2 when one strays off the beaten path? I'd like to through them for myself...

Comment: Any time where you get told to do something usually has additional dialogue if you don't do it immediately. Although this isn't really "hidden" dialogue in the same way as the above is.

Comment: There's even more dialogue if you wait even longer. Even a bit about a French jumpsuit and boybands.

Comment: There are also hidden dialogues anywhere you'd unlock a hidden achievement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some hidden dialog is triggered when you get the ["Good Listener" achievement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbTXHuytW6g). 
Then, at the end of the game, each of the cores you pick up have [loads](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/9.278621-Portal-2-hidden-dialog-SPOILERS-of-course) of [dialog](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20817/what-are-all-the-facts-that-core-3-babbles-about-in-portal-2/20818#20818). The final turret dialog can also be considered hidden, since it requires [translation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/portal-2s-turret-symphony-song-and-lyrics/20784#20784).

Wheatley has tons to say, if you hang around long enough to listen to him. Sometimes you just have to [wait around](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/what-happens-if-i-catch-wheatley/20391#20391), and other times you need to [interact with the environment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zLJ_p2qFyM).

Some of the better easter eggs, however,  don't necessarily contain dialog, but [play](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z6tgSgMS7s) [weird](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LEDH1BJTn4) [sounds](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/4258/portal2sstv.png) or show you [secret](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNdaVFgywOo) [places](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVbqOwh2s3M).

Comment: In addition, there's sometimes extra dialogue based around having already heard some dialogue; the Adventure Sphere will, eventually, suggest you set up a 'zinger' for him. When you attach him, he'll remind you, and when given the opportunity, the Adventure Sphere will chime in with his pre-prepared comeback.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the sound files from the game have been uploaded to YouTube by various people:

- All quotes from GlaDOS (parts [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwYSxnV0ycU), [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4bE9uyru4k), [3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rINE2tQrcvg), [4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GDXd8zQglE), [5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zpyOCQgN0k), [6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGYjB-14wlo))
- All(?) quotes from Wheatley (parts [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y37eezcsIh0), [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9wv4DXC2N8), [3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kIrhXxxxvk), [4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1PhuVixrVA), [5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwabRRwloYI))
- [All quotes from Cave Johnson](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lok_OePmBRM)
- [All quotes from defective turrets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8dUoVpisU8)
- [All quotes from normal turrets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SQB9yv5n80)
- [All quotes from Prometheus *("different")* turret](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mv_iLL4appo&hd=1)
- [All quotes from Fact Sphere](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iAUwamHTM4)
- [All quotes from Adventure Sphere](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmgdtuufi7c)
- [All quotes from Space Sphere](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVn1oQL9sWg)

Answer (score 3):

See `Steam\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\resource\subtitles_english.txt` for all dialogs in the game, there are quite a lot of them and their corresponding sound file names are listed.